# Swift danielgindi/Charts Pie Chart Legend Labels

Tags: swift, charts

I am not getting all the labels to show when doing a legend for a Pie Chart.

here is the code;

```
func AllocationsChart( pieChart: PieChartView ) {

    let entry1 = PieChartDataEntry(value: 65, label: "Stock")
    let entry2 = PieChartDataEntry(value: 35, label: "Bond")

    let dataSet = PieChartDataSet(entries: [entry1, entry2 ] , label: "Allocation" )
    let data = PieChartData(dataSet: dataSet)

    pieChart.data = data

    let labels = ["Stock","Bonds"]   // would like to set the label here

    let colors = [ Color.stock,  Color.bond ]
    dataSet.colors =  colors
    dataSet.sliceSpace = 2

    pieChart.drawHoleEnabled = true
    pieChart.transparentCircleColor = .white
    pieChart.holeRadiusPercent = 0.6667

    let l = pieChart.legend
    l.enabled = true
    l.orientation = .vertical
    l.form = .circle

}
```

and here is the results.

[image: t]

Is there anyway to set the labels like we can do with other charts views like this:

```
 xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: labels)
```

First, why is the bond entry not showing?

Also the color for the legend label does not match entry.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

it was a matter of adding this line of code to the end:

```
pieChart.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

still no idea how to set the labels other than the PieChartDataEntry label?

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Change the label statement to label: "nil" and see what it displays.